# How can I understand these STL programming language codes?

Tags: stl, plc, scada

I am especially looking at line 2 and 4.

1. M004: CLR   ;
2. =     DB888.DBX  642.4;
3. UC    FC  1874;
4. A     L      2.1;
5. SAVE  ;
6. BE    ;
   END_FUNCTION

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems not complete.

M004: CLR ; --> M004 is a jump mark. a previous jump starts at this line. After Jump everything will be cleared.

= DB888.DBX 642.4; --> Assign Bit to RLO.

UC FC 1874; --> Unconsitional Call of FC1874 - so no parameters

A L 2.1; --> does not really fit...

SAVE ; --> Save in BR (so your ENO will be False)

BE ; --> END_FUNCTION unconditional end of block

Check this:
http://www.plcdev.com/files/plcdev/STL-cheat-sheet-by-alphabet.pdf